# OneDrive Recycle Bin Access Denied

Tags: onedrive

After OneDrive was recently updated to 17.3.4724 on Windows 7 x64 I started getting Recycle Bin Access Denied message every time a file from OneDrive folder needs to be deleted.

Anyone else experienced this and most importantly anyone figured out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Windows 7 x64...